# when I use Robolectric+PowerMock+Jacoco do Android LLT, Jacoco cannot work on PowerMock class

Tags: android, powermock, robolectric, jacoco

My build.gradle like this:

```
ext {
    robolectricVersion = "3.3.2"
    powerMockVersion = "1.6.6"
}

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-jacoco:0.2.0'
    }
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')



    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:${robolectricVersion}"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:${powerMockVersion}"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:${powerMockVersion}"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:${powerMockVersion}"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:${powerMockVersion}"
    testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:${powerMockVersion}"

}

jacoco {
    toolVersion "0.7.1.201405082137"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}

def coverageSourceDirs = [
        'src/'
]

task jacocoTestReport(type:JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebugUnitTest") {
    group = "Reporting"

    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: 'build/intermediates/classes/debug',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/*$Proxy.class',
                       '**/*$Stub.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/Manifest*.*']          // 去掉不进行检查的文件
    )

    additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec')

    doFirst {
        new File("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/").eachFileRecurse { file ->
            if (file.name.contains('$$')) {
                file.renameTo(file.path.replace('$$', '$'))
            }
        }
    }

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
        xml.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoXml.xml"
        csv.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoCsv.csv"
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion "0.7.1.201405082137"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}

def coverageSourceDirs = [
        'src/'
]

task jacocoTestReport(type:JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebugUnitTest") {
    group = "Reporting"

    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports"

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: 'build/intermediates/classes/debug',
            excludes: ['**/R.class',
                       '**/*$Proxy.class',
                       '**/*$Stub.class',
                       '**/R$*.class',
                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.*',
                       '**/BuildConfig.*',
                       '**/Manifest*.*']          // 去掉不进行检查的文件
    )

    additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec')

    doFirst {
        new File("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/").eachFileRecurse { file ->
            if (file.name.contains('$$')) {
                file.renameTo(file.path.replace('$$', '$'))
            }
        }
    }

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        html.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoHtml"
        xml.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoXml.xml"
        csv.destination "${buildDir}/jacocoCsv.csv"
    }
}
```

then ,when I run :
    gradlew clean testDebugUnitTest jacocoTestReport --info
I get a result like this:

[ant:jacocoReport] Classes in bundle 'DIAL' do no match with execution data. For
 report generation the same class files must be used as at runtime.
[ant:jacocoReport] Execution data for class com/huawei/restserver/stb/utils/Nati
veUtil does not match.

when I check report , find that NativeUtil.class coverage is 0%

please help me ,more thanks.